# Joining 2 Count Query With Group By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, count

I have 2 query
First one is:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(CustomerId) AS Total
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM Customer
         WHERE JoinYear = 2016 
           AND JoinMonth = 1
           AND JoinWeek = 2 
           AND JoinDay = 1) x
GROUP BY UserId
```

Second one is:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(CustomerId) AS Joined
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM Customer
         WHERE JoinYear = 2016 
           AND JoinMonth = 1
           AND JoinWeek = 2 
           AND JoinDay = 1
           AND JoinStatus = 2) x
GROUP BY UserId
```

Each of them will produce

```
(first query)                (second query)

UserId | Total              UserId | Total
--------------              --------------  
   1   |  10                   1   |   2
   2   |  15                   2   |   5
```

My question is how to join them to table like this?

```
Userid | Total | Joined
-----------------------
   1   |  10   |   2
   2   |  15   |   5
```

Comment: Can you try this

`SELECT x1.UserId, COUNT(x1.CustomerId) AS Total, COUNT(x2.CustomerId) AS Joined
FROM (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE JoinYear = 2016 AND JoinMonth = 1 AND JoinWeek = 2 AND JoinDay = 1) x1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE JoinYear = 2016 AND JoinMonth = 1 AND JoinWeek = 2 AND JoinDay = 1 AND JoinStatus = 2) x2
ON x2.UserId = x1.UserId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is extremely complicated without reason.

Try this:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) Total, SUM(CASE WHEN JoinStatus = 2 THEN 1 END) Joined
FROM Customer
WHERE JoinYear = 2016 AND JoinMonth = 1 AND JoinWeek = 2 AND JoinDay = 1
GROUP BY UserID
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/138af4/1) demonstrating this technique.

Whenever you find yourself with nested subqueries, ask yourself if that's really mandatory.

Comment: hey, I'm sorry, too focusing in your fiddle, this also what I serching for

Answer (score -1):

other oprion:

```
select  UserID, count(Total) as Total, count(Joind) as Joined
from    (
            select  UserId,COUNT(CustomerId) as Total, cast(0 as int) as Joined
            from    Customer
            where   JoinYear = 2016 and JoinMonth = 1 and JoinWeek = 2 and JoinDay = 1
            group by    UserID
            union all
            select  UserId,
                    cast(0 as int) as Total, count(CustomerId) as Joined Customer
            where   JoinYear = 2016 and JoinMonth = 1 and JoinWeek = 2 and JoinDay = 1  and JoinStatus = 2
            group by    UserId
        ) x
group by    x.UserID
```

Comment: don't be rush, your code has a few error like 'JoinMonth = 1=' and etc

Comment: i am sure you can correct syntax error if you have the idea and the locgic